# How to receive and access an image sent in an ios iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

I know the iMessage extensions are pretty new, but this is something I've seen one do and haven't been able to figure out how.

I can insert an image into the iMessage conversation using the MSTemplateLayout.image. This inserts into the message just fine, and is visible to the receiver. However, I'd like the receiver to be able to see this image inside their instance of the app and I cannot seem to access it from the selectedMessage's layout when it is tapped to launch the extension. Is there something I'm missing, or perhaps a better way to send this image across?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

If cast `MSMessageLayout` type to `MSMessageTemplateLayout` type, an image may be accessible.